# Using Web API using VBO No Result

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I just started using Blueprism, we have a requirement to call API with OAuth 2 authentication. I'm trying to get a POC going using WebServices - Oauth 2.0 VBO to make a request like below

Request Inputs
[image]

Request Outputs
[image]

When i submit the request, i do not get any result, i see that token is populated but not the result. can anyone please point what im doing incorrectly here?

i tried directly using the HTTP VBO but no luck

Comment: found the initial issue im using the incorrect token endpoint. we should be using v2 MS endpoint for token

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what i was lacking, im unable to attach scope to the request to get the result. i also changed the way of using Web API services. i used the one from system tab and was able to attach scope for client credential auth type and use actions. once i got that i was able to get the result successfully.